# Is animating directly on DOM nodes a premature optimization?

Tags: reactjs

Vjeux's [presentation on animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtqUJVqpKNo) in React makes the case that animations should be performed by directly manipulating the DOM node

I'm wondering, has anyone actually seen performance hits from animating using setState, or is this a premature optimization?